# What is the term used for a figurine in a board game?

Tags: terminology

I came across the word meeples in reference to a small figurine used in a board game. Are there other words used for the game pieces that people associate with board games such as Monoply that are figurines representing a person or object.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_board_games#piece

Comment: 'Pieces' is probably the hyper-hypernym, and 'tokens' is used for Monopoly pieces. I was going to close-vote on 'not in the lexicon' grounds, but 'meeple' has apparently been accepted.

Comment: I believe 'meeple' refers specifically to a representation of a person: 'token' might be used on the Economic Activity Track, where it would not strictly represent any thing but mark a level of resources; are you asking specifically about "representing a person or object"?

Comment: @TimLymington I was asking about a person, but thought I might clarify the difference if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to piece, the word **token** is commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

If they are particularly detailed, these figurines are called ***miniatures*** or [*miniature figures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miniature_figure_(gaming)&oldid=771413527). From Wikipedia:

> A miniature figure (also known as a miniature, mini, figure, mini-fig or fig) is a small-scale representation of a historical or mythological entity used in miniature wargames, role-playing games, and dioramas. Miniature figures are commonly made of metal, plastic, or paper.

Although the Wikipedia definition connects these to particular game genres, in my experience it is applied to any model that is detailed enough. Note that this is not another term for the things called *meeples*, which are less detailed and more stylized than miniatures. In fact, meeples are often contrasted with miniatures, as in the board gaming podcast [*Meeples & Miniatures*](http://www.meeplesandminiatures.co.uk/) or this Kickstarter campaign promising to make ["Roleplaying Game Meeples as a Miniature Alternative"](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/tinydungeon/fantasy-adventurer-meeples).

I probably would call Monopoly figurines *miniatures*, although they are in a bit of a gray area as they are not-to-scale relative to one another. A [Google image search of "Monopoly miniatures"](https://www.google.com/search?q=monopoly+miniatures+-dollhouse+-%22doll+house%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIro-yls7TAhWD44MKHZIoDOIQsAQIJQ&biw=1920&bih=974) (excluding dollhouse terms, as miniature Monopoly boards are apparently a popular dollhouse entertainment) suggests that others do use this term for Monopoly's iconic race car *et al.*—and also that much of the appeal of various Monopoly special editions is in their various miniatures sets.

For comparison purposes:

**Original meeples, from the board game *Carcassonne***
[image: Close-up picture of wooden "meeples" from boardgame Carcassonne]
Photo by Júlio Reis (User:Tintazul) (Original File) [CC BY-SA 2.5 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5)], via Wikimedia Commons

**Miniature figures (in a Star Wars theme)**
[image: Close-up picture of painted plastic "miniatures" on a scorecard backdrop]
[Source](https://pixabay.com/en/rpg-game-play-miniatures-fun-468920/)

Answer (score 0):

> **piece** *noun*
>
> 12.
>   *Chess, Checkers.*
>   one of the figures, disks, blocks, or the like, of wood, ivory, or other material, used in playing, as on a board or table.

*Dictionary.com*

You would call them **pieces**. This is what you would call the things you play with in chess (knight, king, queen, etc.) and Monopoly (the car, the boot, etc.)

Comment: Please don't use the greengrocer's apostrophe ;)

Comment: There was always a scramble in my house over who was going to be the 'boot' when we played Monopoly. Some might say that I should be given the 'Order of the Boot' whenever I show my face. Ah, well...